# C coding evaluater for coding contest

Tags: c++, c

I am planning to organize a coding contest in my college.
The coding contest is based on solving some C Programs. I need to evaluate whether their program is right are wrong through an application. Is there any sort of application or software to evaluate their programs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's called a compiler.

Comment: If you don't care about coding style then a compiler plus a test unit suite should cover most of what you need.

Comment: Also, be careful that the tester has minimal (no?) permissions

Comment: I understand why this was closed. But give the first poster some love and understand it's a valid question from a beginner. There are all sorts of good answers to this question. I fixed some of the grammar and voted to reopen.

Comment: I don't understand that downvote rage. I consider this retaliation: Someone made the first downvote, and others are poor freeloaders.

Answer (score 6):

[DOMjudge](http://domjudge.sourceforge.net/) is designed to do just that.

It's used for many contests, including the [ICPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACM_International_Collegiate_Programming_Contest).